# Replacing some values in a column based on another data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a feedback dataframe with two feedback categories 'MULTICHOICE' and 'TEXT'. I want to translate questions and responses of 'MULTICHOICE' category and insert in the original dataframe. This is the code I tried.

```
 def translate_feedback_to_english(user_feedback_df):
    feedback_df = user_feedback_df.loc[user_feedback_df.question_type == 'MULTICHOICE']
    responses = translate_responses(feedback_df)
    feedback_df = pd.merge(feedback_df, responses, on="response", how="left")
    user_feedback_df.loc[user_feedback_df.question_type == 'MULTICHOICE','response_en']= feedback_df.loc[:,'response_en']
    return user_feedback_df, feedback_df
```

However The response_en I'm getting contains nulls for MULTICHOICE questions even though my response isn't null. It's not an issue with translating, The same words are translated on top. This is my user_feedback_df

```
        question_type         response response_en
0     MULTICHOICE         Too Much    TOO MUCH
1     MULTICHOICE        Very High   VERY HIGH
2     MULTICHOICE            متدني    INFERIOR
3     MULTICHOICE             ضعيف        WEAK
4     MULTICHOICE             كثير       A LOT
..            ...              ...         ...
229   MULTICHOICE             كافي         NaN
230          TEXT  Achanda Overall         NaN
231   MULTICHOICE            متدني         NaN
232   MULTICHOICE              جيد         NaN
233   MULTICHOICE         غير كافي         NaN
```

However, Everything is correctly translated in my feedback_df.

```
    question_type   response response_en
0     MULTICHOICE   Too Much    TOO MUCH
1     MULTICHOICE  Very High   VERY HIGH
2     MULTICHOICE      متدني    INFERIOR
3     MULTICHOICE       ضعيف        WEAK
4     MULTICHOICE       كثير       A LOT
..            ...        ...         ...
196   MULTICHOICE      مقبول  ACCEPTABLE
197   MULTICHOICE       كافي      ENOUGH
198   MULTICHOICE      متدني    INFERIOR
199   MULTICHOICE        جيد        GOOD
200   MULTICHOICE   غير كافي  NOT ENOUGH
enter code here
```

Comment: Does your `responses` dataframe have by any chance only one row with the translation for a word that appears many times on the `user_feedback` dataframe? For example, the translation for كافي ("A LOT") appears more than once on `responses`?

Comment: No My response table has no duplicates.

Comment: You should have duplicates on `responses`, since from your example you need to have duplicates  to fill `user_feedback_df.loc[user_feedback_df.question_type == 'MULTICHOICE`,' response_en`]

Comment: I replaced values of my user_feedback_df with feedback_df not responses. feedback_df is a subset of user_feedback_df with only MULTICHOICE questions, I merged that with responses and tried to replace in user_feedback_df. Also I edited my answer you can see my feedback_df, but not user_feedback_df.